# QueryDSL predicate bindings "or" between multiple path

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I have a Spring boot Rest API witch use *Querydsl* predicate for filtering, I use the *QuerydslBinderCustomizer* on my *MongoRepository* to bind properties path to customize the query.

The default behavior when multiple search values are set for the same path is an OR operator between these values.

But when multiple path are used and AND operator is used.

What I want to do is to put an OR operator between multiple chosen path.

I found this quite clear documentation but didin't find an answer in it : https://gt-tech.bitbucket.io/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/README.html

Today I have :

***CONTROLLER***

```
public Page<Document> find(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Document.class) Predicate predicate) {
        return repository.findAll(predicate);
    }
```

***REPOSITORY***

```
public interface Repository extends
        MongoRepository<Document, String>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<EventRuleDocument>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QEventRuleDocument> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDocument doc) {
        bindings.bind(doc.prop1).first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
        bindings.bind(doc.prop2).first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
        bindings.bind(doc.prop3).first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Witch gives me the predicate : `prop1 == v1 AND prop2 == v2 AND prop3 == v3`

What I would like to achieve is : `prop1 == v1 OR prop2 == v2 OR prop3 == v3`

Is this possible using *QuerydslBinderCustomizer* ?

Or do I have to create a custom controller and/or repository method ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it's not yet possible to perform a cross-property OR with  QuerydslBinderCustomizer (at least I haven't found a way yet), so I'd go for a custom controller. As changing a default behavior is counter-intuitive and someone might misuse the filter, make sure to use a really explicit endpoint path, such as _/docs/search/or?prop1=...&prop2=...&..._ or _/docs/filter/or?..._

Comment: After putting more thought into it I now realize that the feature I want is a general multi properties search. With that in mind my research will probably be more relevant to my goal.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDocument root) {

StringPath[] multiPropertySearchPaths = new StringPath[] {root.prop1, root.prop2, root.prop3};

/**
 * Binds prop1, prop2 and prop3 in OR clause
 * This binding will activate when one of the given properties are searched in query params
 */
bindings.bind(multiPropertySearchPaths).all(new MultiValueBinding<StringPath, String>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate bind(StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        // Bind paths present in array multiPropertySearchPaths with incoming values
        for (StringPath propertyPath : multiPropertySearchPaths) {
            values.forEach(value -> predicate.or(propertyPath.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
        }
        return predicate;
    }
});
}
```

It will generate sql like:

```
select * from document
where
    lower(document.prop1) like ?1 
    or lower(document.prop2) like ?1 
    or lower(document.prop3) like ?1
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding the same path multiple times only results in ORs between multiple occurrences of the *same* property, but not between *different* properties.

I propose the following:

```
public Page<Document> find(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Document.class, bindings = OrDslBindings.class) Predicate predicate) {
  return repository.findAll(predicate);
}
```

```
public class OrDslBindings implements QuerydslBinderCustomizer<EntityPath<?>> {

  @Override
  public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, EntityPath<?> entityPath) {
    bindings.bind(String.class).all(new MultiValueOrBinding());
  }

  private static class MultiValueOrBinding implements MultiValueBinding<StringPath, String> {

    private boolean first = true;
    private final BooleanBuilder orPredicate = new BooleanBuilder();

    @Override
    public Optional<Predicate> bind(StringPath path, Collection<? extends S> values) {
      values.forEach(value -> orPredicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));

      if (first) {
        first = false;
        return Optional.of(orPredicate);
      } else {
        return Optional.empty();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The binding stores the state and appends each property with OR. It is returned only once, otherwise the framework will duplicate each OR-group and add ANDs between them, which is superfluous.